# Primefaces changing value of inputSwitch inside deferred outputPanel

Tags: jsf, primefaces

We are using JSF and Primefaces to control a SparkStream inside a Web-Application running on Tomcat. When we start or stop this Stream this takes about 15seconds in which the Web-GUI keeps loading.

Now we wanted to use deferred loading for long-loading content to make sure the Web-GUI is still accessible even if the Bean needs some time for responding. Anyway if we do so, our p:inputSwitch does not work correctly anymore. **Everytime we load or refresh the page, the value in the Bean is set to false.**

```
<h:form>
  <p:panel id="control" header="Streaming-Control" collapsed="false" toggleable="true">
    <p:outputPanel deferred="true">
      <p:inputSwitch id="test" value="#{SomeBean.someBoolean}">
        <p:ajax update="test"/>
      </p:inputSwitch>      
    </p:outputPanel>
  </p:panel>
</h:form>
```

We need to put the inputSwitch inside the deferred outputPanel because it should not be accessible until the whole page is rendered completely (which means the Stream is running or stopped, but not starting or being stopped atm).
PrimeFaces Version is 6.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always try the newest version ;)
It could be fixed already: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/2912